# spring-boot adding a custom command to actuatorshell in java

Tags: shell, spring-boot

I am trying to add a java command to spring-actuator's ssh remote shell in a spring-boot applicaton.  The spring-boot version is 1.2.3.RELEASE.

My sample command is just named 'kafka' and I tried placing it on the classpath in both /crash/commands as well as just /commands.  It is never found - it doesn't show up in the help or actually work.

Is there some way to ask the remote shell to tell me what it's scanning/finding when it starts?

Things I have tried include specfically overriding shell.commandPathPatterns though the default seems like it should cover it.

My command - for testing - is very simple:

```
package commands;
@Usage("Kafka utility commands")
public class kafka extends BaseCommand {

    @Command
    public Object main(InvocationContext<ObjectName> context) {
       return "it's all good";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After one hour of debugging I've found that the CRaSH remote shell looks for files with the extensions `.groovy` or `.java` within the packages are `commands` and `crash.commands`. The found files are compiled to bytecode, compiler errors are ignored.

I presume you use something like Maven. When you put your command into src/main/java then Maven will compile it as .class file and CRaSH will not find it. When you put your command into src/main/resources then Maven will *not* compile it and keep it as .java file instead.

The solution (which is quite odd for me) is to put your java command file into src/main/resources (package `commands` or `crash.commands`) so you have a `.java` source file in your target directory or JAR.

I tested it with spring-boot 1.2.1.RELEASE (crash.shell: 1.3.0) which should not be much different than 1.2.3.RELEASE (crash.shell: 1.3.1).

Comment: For me this only worked when also setting `shell.command-path-patterns=classpath*:/src/main/resources/crash/commands/**` (can be done in addition to the defaul configuration)